# Feeding to std::stringstream and simultaneously passing it as argument to a function c++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, ostream, temporary

I have the following functions

```
void Assembly::push_back(stringstream& ss){
    instructions->push_back(ss.str());
}

std::ostream& pad(std::ostream& os) {
    return os <<"\t"<<std::left<< std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(8);
}
```

where `instructions` is a list of strings. I want to do sth like

```
Assembly outfile;
stringstream ss;
outfile.push_back(ss<<pad<<"addiu"<<"$sp, $sp, -8");
```

but I get an error from the compiler

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>' to 'std::stringstream& {aka std::basic_stringstream<char>&}'
```

I tried changing the definition of `push_back` to take `std::basic_ostream<char>` but it still did not compile.

Basically what I want to do is be able to push_back a string which has the alignment that `pad` adds. It is also essential that I am able to call `Assembly::push_back` in a single line (I know that

```
Assembly outfile;
stringstream ss;
ss<<pad<<"addiu"<<"$sp, $sp, -8";
outfile.push_back(ss);
```

works, but it requires two lines of code to make the proper call). I am also open to solutions which overload the `operator<<` for `Assembly` or allow me to accomplish the required behavior in a single line.

Comment: Why not make some simple `Instruction` class that will do the formatting, and has various constructors (or potentially subclasses) to deal with the necessary combinations of parameters?

Comment: Why is it "essential" to have the `push_back` call on one line?

Comment: Yes, making a separate class will work, just wondering whether I can do it with the standard library.

Comment: I want to have `push_back` call in one line because I call it many times in a row which makes the code look very messy

Comment: Yes I tried `push_back(const std::stringstream& ss);`, it did not work

Comment: Did you try changing the parameter type to `std::ostream`? That's the return type of the `stringstream::operator<<` function.

Comment: Michael `std::ostream` works. +1 for simplicity. If you want you can put it in an answer so that I accept it

Comment: If you simply change the parameter to `Assembly::push_back(std::ostream &os)`, as I think you mean, then you can't call `str()`. You could cast back to `std::stringstream &`, but in the general case that wouldn't be typesafe.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `pad()` take and return a `std::stringstream`, and then also add this:

```
template <typename T>
std::stringstream &
operator<<(std::stringstream &ss, const T &o) {
    static_cast<std::ostream &>(ss) << o; // Prevent recursion.
    return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think the problem is. This won't work because the return value of `ss << anything` is always an `std::ostream&` which is a parent of `std::stringstream` and does not satisfy the argument for your `push_back()` function.

```
void push_back(const std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::cout << "push: " << ss.str() << '\n';
}

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    // what gets sent to the function is an std::ostream&
    // which is an incompatible type.
    push_back(ss << "one " << 2 << ' ' << 3.0); // fail
}
```

The way to fix this is to create an overload for `operator<<(std::stringstream&` that returns the correct type:

```
template<typename DataType>
std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream& ss, const DataType& data)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(ss) << data;
    return ss;
}
```

Now calling `<<` on a `std::stringstream` will return a `std::stringstream&` which is acceptable as your `push_back()` parameter.

```
void push_back(const std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::cout << "push: " << ss.str() << '\n';
}

int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    // Now the << returns the correct type (std::stringstream&)
    push_back(ss << "one " << 2 << ' ' << 3.0); // good
}
```